# draw on top of button in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to draw a circle on top of a button centered at its center when I click it.
I tried to add a canvas to do so but when I try to pack it in **init** to the root
then I get an error that i'm tring to use geometry and grid at the same time.

If I don't pack it to the root then when I click a button nothing happens.

thanks

```
from tkinter import *

class Game:
    def __init__(self, root, size):
        self.root = root
        self.size = size
        self.turn = "red"
        self.board = self.init_board()
        self.current_turn_label = None
        self.load_button = None
        self.save_button = None
        self.init_head()
        self.canvas = Canvas(root)
        # self.canvas.pack() # ERROR

    def init_board(self):
        board = [[0] * self.size for _ in range(self.size)]
        for row in range(self.size):
            for col in range(self.size):
                board[row][col] = Button(width=5, height=2, bg='white',
                                command= lambda r=row, c=col: self.handle_click(r,c))
                board[row][col].grid(row=row+1, column=col)
        return board

    def handle_click(self, r, c):
        print(f"inside click, r: {r} c: {c}")
        button = self.board[r][c]
        x, y = self.location(r, c)
        # draw circle at center of button of color self.turn
        self.canvas.create_oval(x, y, x + button.winfo_width(), y + button.winfo_height(), fill=self.turn)
        # nothing happens

    def load_game(self):
        print("inside load game")

    def save_game(self):
        print("inside save game")

    def location(self, r, c):
        button = self.board[r][c]
        x, y = button.winfo_x(), button.winfo_y()
        return x, y

    def init_head(self):
        self.current_turn_label = Label(text=f"turn: {self.turn}")
        self.current_turn_label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)

        self.load_button = Button(text="Load", command=self.load_game)
        self.load_button.grid(row=0, column=3)

        self.save_button = Button(text="Save", command=self.save_game)
        self.save_button.grid(row=0, column=4)


root = Tk()
game = Game(root, 5)
mainloop()
```

Comment: You can't draw over a widget. The underlying os requires that widgets are above shapes.

Comment: Use an image with a circle of the required color and then set it as the image background of the button using `image` option when the button is clicked.